# Viewbox and text bad rendering

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've a ViewBox that's have this content:

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Stretch="Fill" >
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
       <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Latest Match" FontSize="10"/>
       <TextBlock Background="WhiteSmoke" Width="300"/>
       <TextBlock Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
       <TextBlock Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
       <TextBlock Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
       <TextBlock Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
   </StackPanel>
</Viewbox>
```

when I enlarge the window I get this:

[image]

how you can see the text Latest match seems compressed in width, how can I fix this having a text that doesn't compress in width?

Comment: You should rethink the width definition in `<TextBlock Background="WhiteSmoke" Width="300"/>`... it is forcing itself on the whole layout, which doesn't really help inside the `Viewbox`

Answer (score 1):

You must set a different value to Stretch property of Viewbox.
Probably Uniform in you case.

See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.media.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: with stretch the controls doesn't fit to top and down but remain to center

Comment: @AgainMe you should probably explain exactly what you want to see. And again, just don't define a width of 300 when you don't like the effect of to much width being pushed together.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Stretch="Fill" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Latest Match" FontSize="10" />
            <TextBlock Background="WhiteSmoke" Width="300"/>
            <TextBlock Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
            <TextBlock Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
            <TextBlock Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
            <TextBlock Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="0,5,0,0" />

        </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, you just re-posted his code with a grid added at the top...

Comment: @BrandonKramer-i added but doesnt work.. and i apply code inside grid its working fine..once again u check it.

Comment: That's because you are giving it as much space to expand as it wants.  try setting the window size to 300.  It looks fine if it has more space, but once you reduce it, it begins to look compressed like the image.  Also, I *did* test your code, and it does not fix the issue.